# Redirect stdout and stderr into an Installer Variable [Install4j]

Tags: variables, redirect, stdout, stderr, install4j

I've been using Install4j for creating a cool installer for a Java Application and did a lot of things with it. Now I want to know what is happening with the commands I'm executing into a BAT file with a "Run Executable or Batch file" Action. So, I read this Action documentation in the manual and it says that the action can, eventually, redirect STDOUT and STDERR into an Installer variable.
So, I've created two Installer variables, stdout_response and stderr_response.
This both variables are defined with a default value "default_stdout" and "default_stderr".

In the Action, I choose the option "Redirect to Installer Variable" related to both STDOUT and STDERR responses, and set my installer variables for this redirection.

My BAT files performs some ECHOs so I think something is going to get out of there eventually.

After my "Run Executable or Batch file" Action, I have defined a "Run Script" Action where I simply perform a System.out.println(...) over my installer variables so the next code is executed:

System.out.println(context.getVariable("stdout_response")); //Prints my STDOUT installer variable.

When my installer reaches this Action, it prints an Empty String "" so something is being set into my Installer variable, but not my wanted values.

For my "stderr_response", the value set is something like "^C"

Is there somnething I'm missing. Maybe the BAT file must establish some internal redirection.

Thanks in advance!!!

EDITION!!!! Added More Information

My "Run Executable or Batch File" Action configuration

(Can't submit images yet, but I leave the links below)

[Configuration](http://s28.postimg.org/5yiqf8xnx/Run_Executable_Conf.png)

My verification Script in to "Run Script" action after the "Run Executable or Batch file" action

```
System.out.println("**********************************************************************************************************");
System.out.println(String.format("Test de Variable STDOUT: %s", (String)context.getVariable("script_response_stdout")));
System.out.println(String.format("Test de Variable STDERR: %s", (String)context.getVariable("script_response_stderr")));
System.out.println("**********************************************************************************************************");
return false;
```

My Batch file

```
@echo off
cls

set mysql_msi=%1
set mysql_svname=%2
set mysql_data_dir=%3
set mysql_install_dir=%4
set mysql_admin_user=%5
set mysql_admin_password=%6
set mysql_port=%7
set mysql_instance=%8
set mysql_exe=%9

echo mysql_msi: %mysql_msi%
echo mysql_svname: %mysql_svname%
echo mysql_admin_user: %mysql_admin_user%
echo mysql_admin_password: %mysql_admin_password%
echo mysql_port: %mysql_port%
echo mysql_instance: %mysql_instance%
echo mysql_exe: %mysql_exe%

msiexec /i %mysql_msi% /qn INSTALLDIR=%mysql_install_dir% /L* C:\MSI-MySQL-Log.txt

echo Mysql Instance Configuration

%mysql_instance% -i -q ServiceName=%mysql_svname% RootPassword=%mysql_admin_password% ServerType=DEVELOPMENT DatabaseType=MYISAM Port=%mysql_port% RootCurrentPassword=%mysql_admin_password%

echo Terminated
```

Can't post more links so I'l comment them down here!!!!

Comment: Do you have the "Wait for termination" property selected? It will only work in that case.

Comment: Hi Ingo!!! thanks for your interest. Yeah, I have selected that property, in fact Install4J forced me to select that for being able to select "Installer Variable" in the redirection option.

Comment: All right, I forgot that it did that. Can you select the "Show console window" property and check what the output should actually be?

Comment: Ok, I'll give you all the information I can as an Edition to the main post!!!

Comment: What is currently printed in console (For bat files, another console is opened):

[Starting_Action](http://s30.postimg.org/nqmvuf0w1/Console_Output_Starting_Action.png)


[Bat_File_Output](http://s13.postimg.org/wwhj9mfrr/Console_Output_Bat_File.png)


[Finished_Action](http://s23.postimg.org/fgcc4o9nf/Console_Output_Finished_Action.png)

The error message is related to the "return false" response of the created script.

Comment: Did you always have the "Show console window" property checked? Because I just verified that redirection does not work if that property is selected, but it works otherwise.

Comment: Yep, maybe that's the problem. While debuging the created installer I always use the "show console" option because I want to know whats is happening there. Maybe the redirection should work no matter the "show console" is selected or not. I'll do some tests and post the result.

Comment: Ok, that was the problem, I was always debuging with show console because this option does not have any tip about what will not work when it is used.... Ingo, can you post that as an answer so I can mark it as this question solution.

Comment: In addition, I'll ask another thing related to this question. Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: I've put this as an answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the the "Show console window" property of the "Run executable or batch file" action is selected, the redirection does not work.

In install4j 5.1.12, it will no longer be possible to select this combination.